# Error: unexpected type required: variable found: value

Tags: java

Im trying to make this variable int stringSize to print "ok" or "not ok" depending on the if statement.
Heres what i have:

```
     int stringSize = (n_1 + n_2 + n_3);
         if (stringSize < 20){
             String.valueOf(stringSize) = "ok";

         }else if (stringSize > 20){
             String.valueOf(stringSize) = "not ok";

         }
```

Theres more code but its irrelevant to the question, I think. Nevertheless everything is defined except until here.

I know i cant just put it equals to the "ok" so how do i get the stringSize to print either "ok" or "not ok"?

Im a beginner, so lets be nice and i tried looking up other solutions but none were similar to my case 
TY in advance

Comment: `String.valueOf(stringSize)` is not a variable, and you cannot assign it a value of `"ok"`

Comment: I know that. But im asking what i should try instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `stringSize` is an integer, to store a string like "ok" or "not ok", you should use a String variable. Declare a String variable and store the value in that. For example -

```
int stringSize = (n_1 + n_2 + n_3);
String message = null;
if (stringSize < 20){
    message = "ok";
}else if (stringSize > 20){
    message = "not ok";
}
```

Moreover, [String.valueOf()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_valueof.htm) returns the string representation of the parameter where you cannot assign another value. For example, `String.valueOf(stringSize)` will return "15" if the value of `stringSize` is 15.

---

> How do i get the `stringSize` to print either "ok" or "not ok"?

Just put the following line wherever you want to print the message. [following the example given above]

```
if(message != null){
    System.out.println(message);
}
```

Comment: I tried what you said. But if i put message in the final print statement, it says variable message is not initialized. Do you know what this means?

Comment: Thank You it worked! Do you mind explaining why its equal to null (so i know)? what does that do?

Comment: @madcity its just an initial value. you can initialize the string variable with some other value. say, your so name "madcity". since there is an if/else condition, anyway the variable is going to be assign with either `ok` or `not ok`. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

`String.valueOf(stringSize)` is an expression, you cannot assign a value to an expression. In fact, an expression *has* a value. All you need is to define a variable of type `String`: `String message = "ok";`

Comment: Haha true, did not read the code (and the variable name... which should have hinted me it's an int). Fixing

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a value to the result of an expression, however you mentioned you want to print the value. You can do that. Like,

```
if (stringSize < 20){
    System.out.println("ok");
} else { // <-- if it should be ok or not ok, use else.
    System.out.println("not ok");
}
```

Comment: Well i wanted to print it in the final statement i have at the end.

Comment: Then move it to the end.